# Migrating from Bootstrap v3.0.1 to Bootstrap v3.1.1

Tags: migration, twitter-bootstrap-3, upgrade

I developed the project in Bootstrap v3.0.1. Now some bugs were fixed and released the version Bootstrap v3.1.1. is there any guide to Migrating from Bootstrap v3.0.1 to Bootstrap v3.1.1.

Comment: If you could mark one of the answers as accepted, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just backed up first, then copied the new files over the top of the old ones.

I had no problems.

The main point is BACKUP before you start.

Keith

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap follows Semantic Versioning, so v3.1.1 is backward-compatible with v3.0.1, except for one exceptional change regarding how the `remote` option of modals works, which happened in v3.1.0 (see the "Remote modal content" section of http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/01/30/bootstrap-3-1-0-released/ for details).

You can also read each of the relevant release blog posts (which have the changelogs) if you're really paranoid: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/